# How do I wait and get the result from a Promise in the service layer in Play Framework 2.2.1?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I need to get the value from a `Promise` returned by a method from the service layer. And I need to do this inside the `Action<?> onRequest(Request req, Method actionMethod){}` of `Global` class that extends `GlobalSettings`. I need to get the value from the returned `Promise` before calling another method from the service layer and before `onRequest` method of the `Global` class returns.

I've a method named `await` but I can't from the examples I googled where this method is coming from. I'm not even sure if that method can give me the result.

I'm doing this in Java.

EDIT: added some source code

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationService authorizationService;

    @Override
    public Action<?> onRequest(Request req, Method actionMethod) 
    {
        // for simplicity's sake
        String username = req.getHeader( "email" );

        Promise<Boolean> promiseOfBoolean =
            this.getAuthorizationService().isUserRegistered( username );

        if( /* promiseOfBoolean is true */ true )
        {
            // do something here
            // return new action here
            return null;
        }
        else {          
            return super.onRequest(req, actionMethod);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you include your current code?

Comment: @Ryan Edited the question to include the source code. This is oversimplified.